# Chat search for terms with hyphens fails

Tags: bug, chat, search

[Searching for "t-mobile"](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=T-mobile&user=&room=89) in chat fails even though there are [occurrences of that string.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mobile&user=&room=89) This seems to have to do with the hyphen.

Comment: Probably minor or even by design, but ...

Comment: You've been around long enough to know we don't like hyphens...

Comment: @Yannis that *probably* is the problem.

Comment: No idea, (bad) joke / reference to the hyphenated site. ;)

Comment: [What?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j4kKL.png)

Comment: Then there's [this search](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=t+and+mobile&user=&room=). Confusing!